# JavaScript serialization of form not correct when added as a property of another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I was able to serialize my form and pass the object to my MVC controller.  Here is a cut down version of the code.

```
public void Test(ComplexType model)
{                
   // do stuff with model
}
```

with the JavaScript:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/CmaTestRun/Test/',
        data: $('#theForm').serializeArray()
 }).......
```

However, I then realized that I needed to pass additional data along with the serialized form so I made the following changes.

I created a class to that would hold the original `ComplexType` and an `integer` value and would be passed to the controller:

```
public class TestObject
{
   public int TestId { get; set; }
   public ComplexType TestModel { get; set;}
}
```

And my controller action:

```
 public void Test(TestObject model)
 {                          
 }
```

Finally, in my JavaScript, I made the following changes:

```
var TestObject = {
    TestId:99,
    ComplexType: $('#theForm').serializeArray()
}      

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/CmaTestRun/Test/',
    data: TestObject
})
```

When I run and step into the controller, the TestObject is passed and TestId is 99.  However, although my `ComplexType` has the correct structure, its properties are all null.

How should I change the code so that everything is populated correctly?

EDIT - Serialized Form

The properties are a bit different from the original post.  The collapsed objects follow the same structure as the expanded ones.

[image]

Comment: try do the TestObject extend of Test, insted do a composition, and add the new field as a hidden input on your form.

Comment: Thanks.  I have got this working but would like to know why my original code is broken.

Comment: Can you show your $('#theForm').serializeArray() result here, so i can see if what i thought is correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this, first serialize the form and then push extra data.

```
var params = $('#theForm').serializeArray();
params.push({name: 'testId', value: 99});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/CmaTestRun/Test/',
    data: params
})
```

and you can also use jquery $.param() [param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1p9gx3y2/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var TestObject = {
    TestId:99,
    ComplexType: $('#theForm').serializeArray()
}  

var shallowEncoded = $.param( TestObject, false );
    var shallowDecoded = decodeURIComponent( shallowEncoded );
console.log(shallowEncoded);
    console.log(shallowDecoded);
})
```

and here is controller: Nothing to change. Modelbinder will take care of it.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(TestObject)
        {


         }
```

and if you want to keep them seperate in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(ComplexType model, int testId)
{                
   // do stuff with model
}
```

and keep the model like it was before. modelbinder populates the model from http form collection from posted data.

Comment: Thanks, and what in the controller method?

Comment: no matter how I try it, the properties of ComplexType are null.  TestId is always fine.

Comment: Can you post output of params passed into Ajax call?

Comment: I will try, I have changed the code and have got something working by extending my 'ComplexType' to include the TestId and then using the 'push' method as you suggested at first.  It's not very intuitive though, I'd really like to know why none of the other methods work...but need to park it for now I think :( Thanks for your help by the way.